# Removing all unnecessary fonts from system

Tags: fonts, 20.04

My system was upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04, then to 19.10 and finally to 20.04. I have been using it for more than 15 months as my primary computer. This is a typical default Ubuntu installation with some extra manual "apt install"s.

I noticed that there are a lot of fonts and font variations (mostly Asian) that I haven't installed explicitly. Selecting a font in an application (e.g. in LibreOffice) is cumbersome because of the long font drop-down list box. Also, I think that having so many unneeded fonts will make applications slower and is a waste of system resources.

I would like to remove most of the seemingly unnecessary fonts from my system. However, I am not sure which ones are necessary for proper system and core applications operation. Are there any pointers on how to decide on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the fonts I purge from a new installation. Clearly, the list is **not** suitable for all users:

```
sudo apt purge \
fonts-beng-extra \
fonts-beng \
fonts-deva-extra \
fonts-deva \
fonts-gargi \
fonts-gubbi \
fonts-gujr-extra \
fonts-gujr \
fonts-guru-extra \
fonts-guru \
fonts-indic \
fonts-kacst-one \
fonts-kacst \
fonts-kalapi \
fonts-khmeros-core \
fonts-knda \
fonts-lao \
fonts-lklug-sinhala \
fonts-lohit-beng-assamese \
fonts-lohit-beng-bengali \
fonts-lohit-deva \
fonts-lohit-gujr \
fonts-lohit-guru \
fonts-lohit-knda \
fonts-lohit-mlym \
fonts-lohit-orya \
fonts-lohit-taml-classical \
fonts-lohit-taml \
fonts-lohit-telu \
fonts-mlym \
fonts-nakula \
fonts-navilu \
fonts-noto-cjk \
fonts-orya-extra \
fonts-orya \
fonts-pagul \
fonts-sahadeva \
fonts-samyak-deva \
fonts-samyak-gujr \
fonts-samyak-mlym \
fonts-samyak-taml \
fonts-sarai \
fonts-sil-abyssinica \
fonts-sil-padauk \
fonts-smc-anjalioldlipi \
fonts-smc-chilanka \
fonts-smc-dyuthi \
fonts-smc-karumbi \
fonts-smc-keraleeyam \
fonts-smc-manjari \
fonts-smc-meera \
fonts-smc-rachana \
fonts-smc-raghumalayalamsans \
fonts-smc-suruma \
fonts-smc-uroob \
fonts-smc \
fonts-taml \
fonts-telu-extra \
fonts-telu \
fonts-thai-tlwg \
fonts-tibetan-machine \
fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-garuda \
fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-kinnari \
fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-laksaman \
fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-loma \
fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-mono \
fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-norasi \
fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-purisa \
fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-sawasdee \
fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-typewriter \
fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-typist \
fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-typo \
fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-umpush \
fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf \
fonts-tlwg-waree \
fonts-yrsa-rasa
```

Note that the list includes `fonts-noto-cjk`.

Comment: Thanks @DK Bose for the list. I will accept this as the correct answer, but **any comments on your suggested action are also highly welcome**.

Comment: I removed all the fonts you listed from my system (some of them were not installed BTW). There seems no problem. **Removing the clutter from the font lists is rather relieving. Thanks again.** In my comment I didn't mean your comments that you had removed, but any potential comments from other users *about deleting these fonts*.

Comment: After removing these fonts, I have seen that there as some fonts with some strange names. I inspected these with `font-manager` and I saw that there are nothing special about them. Their names are `C059`, `D050000L`, `P052`, and `Z003`.

Comment: What do you see with `apt list --installed | grep -i fonts`? Do they show up there? But see https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/urw-base35-fonts/tree/master/fonts.

Comment: They are part of `fonts-urw-base35` package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/fonts-urw-base35 . I think this package is installed by default. Does your installation(s) contain it? Note: fonts-urw-base35/focal,focal,now 20170801.1-3 all [installed,automatic]

Comment: I don't see it in Kubuntu 18.04. I'll check on some other systems later.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Okay, I checked on Kubuntu **20**.04 and it's there with `[installed,automatic]`. I can't figure what package pulled it in as a dependency. Plus, it's there in the manifests of several *buntu 20.04 isos. I'm not going to remove from my system (for now).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to remove a font package that is required for another package, you will be asked whether it is ok to remove that package too.

I use the Synaptic package manager for wholesale font removal. In the settings menu, *'Ask to confirm changes that also affect other packages'* is **checked**, *'Consider recommended packages as dependencies'* is **unchecked**.