# Too many Noto fonts after upgrading to 23.10

Tags: upgrade, fonts, 23.10

After upgrading to 23.10 (from 23.04) I noticed that on my system there are more than 220 **Noto** fonts. This is kind of insane. In today's world of UTF standard why do we have so many fonts for some languages? How, can I safely get rid of them?

Please, note that his question is different than one of my [previous question about fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239037/removing-all-unnecessary-fonts-from-system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GunnarHjalmarsson's answer was about purging the package `fonts-noto-core` that contains all these fonts. I am grateful for this answer and especially its comments.

The `fonts-noto-core` package really contains 268 font files:

```
$ apt-file list fonts-noto-core | grep -c \.ttf\$
268
```

However, some of these may be used by my Latin-based system, since this package was  "`[installed,automatic]`" during the upgrade process. I wanted a method to "disable" these "asiatic fonts" that I really don't seem to need.

I noticed that the `font-manager` tool allows me to select those fonts from the list and "disable" them. After that, a file called `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/78-Reject.conf` is created under the current's user home directory. This XML file will list the fonts that have been "rejected".

Afterwards, my applications will not list these fonts in their Font dialogs. And I think this is a better solution, since it is user-based and not system-based.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that method to disable specific fonts. While some would consider it a cumbersome method, it's perfectly fine. However, I don't agree on the reason you stated for preferring that method. Yes, `fonts-noto-core` is installed by default, but since it's only recommended, the package can be safely uninstalled. There are other font packages for rendering latin scripts, some already installed and otherwise in the archive. After all it's just a font package.

Answer (score 5):

Please ask Google about the number of fonts.

Ubuntu wants to cover a large number of languages by default. But one advantage, compared with the previous font setup, is that users, who don't care about global coverage, can uninstall one single package:

```
sudo apt purge fonts-noto-core
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My original question was about (1) why does a single _UTF_ font not cover all the languages and (2) if all these automatically installed **Noto** fonts (installed by a single package) can be safely (or selectively) removed.

Comment: @FedKad: I think I understood what you asked about. As regards (1) Google chose to create many fonts, and I don't know their considerations about that choice. As regards (2) I thought I answered that...

Comment: @FedKad A single font file cannot cover every possible character and language. A truetype file is limited to 65K glyphs, and multiple fonts must overlap the same space of Unicode codepoints to cover all languages because of things like [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) and similar.